# Limit Responsive Areas for Page Curl Transition

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am using the View Transition Style "UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl" to navigate  book-like through multiple pages/views. Currently the whole left and right side of the page - from top to bottom - "listen" to tap or swipe gestures resulting in page turns.

How can I limit these responsive areas to the very bottom left and bottom right areas of the screen (see the colored spots in the screenshot) to avoid conflicts with other buttons to be placed on the screen?

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my current setup of the UIPageViewController with page curl:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin] 
                                                    forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

[self setPageController:[[UIPageViewController alloc]initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                                                       navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                     options:options]];
[pageController setDataSource:self];
[[pageController view] setFrame:[[self view]bounds]];

RollViewController *rvc = [[RollViewController alloc]init];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:rvc];

[pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers
                         direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                          animated:NO
                        completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:pageController];
[[self view]addSubview:[pageController view]];
[pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Did you solve this?